# google chrome security certificate not valid

Tags: windows, google-chrome

When I open Google chrome and acess social network like facebook,ymail,Gmail,twitter,my space etc. It would say like this below:

> The server's security certificate is not yet valid!
>
> You attempted to reach accounts.google.com, but the server presented a
>   certificate that is not yet valid. No information is available to
>   indicate whether that certificate can be trusted. Google Chrome cannot
>   reliably guarantee that you are communicating with accounts.google.com
>   and not an attacker. You should ensure that your clock and time zone
>   are set correctly on your computer. If they are not, you should
>   correct any issues and refresh this page. If they are correct, you
>   should not proceed.

Please tell the process to access to valid certificate

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a site with a security certificate error, you should see a a padlock and "https://" crossed out in the address bar. Click on the lock icon and you should see a display about the certificate. There will be a link to view "Certificate Information".

This will open a dialog menu with the certificate details. Pay close attention to the "Validity Period" and note the date and year. Now double and triple check your computer's clock. Make sure your computer's clock is set to the correct year.

What is happening is Chrome is looking at your system date/time and comparing it to the certificate details when you connect to these sites. In your case, the hint to the issue is:

> a certificate that is **not yet** valid.

The date Chrome is getting from your system is set to before the "Issued On" date you saw when you looked at the "Validity Period" section of the certificate.